Limit process of a sequence of Gaussian variables on mesh grid going to zero
Consider the interval $[0,1]$ and a partition $\mathscr{P}_n = \{ [t_i,t_{i+1}), \, i=1,\ldots,N_n \, : \, 0=t_0 < \ldots < t_{N_n} = 1\}$. Suppose that for all $i$ and $t \in [t_i,t_{i+1})$, we define a process $X(t)$ such that $X(t)$ is the same on each sub interval $[t_i,t_{i+1})$, thus $X(t) \neq X(s)$ only if $t \in [t_i,t_{i+1})$, $s \in [s_j,s_{j+1})$ and $i \neq j$. Suppose also that $X(t) \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$ for $t \in [t_i,t_{i+1})$ and $X(s) \perp X(t)$ if $t \in [t_i,t_{i+1})$, $s \in [s_j,s_{j+1})$ and $i \neq j$. Now let the mesh grid of the partition go to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$. What is the limiting process?

Should there be any limiting process? I suppose $\mu_1$ might be $\ne\mu_2$. So I don't see any meaningful limit. And did you mean $0=t_1<\dots$? And is $N_n$ increasing as you increase $n$?

$\mu_i, \sigma_i^2$ implicitly depend on $n$, and you haven't said how.  Everything depends on what they are.

Generally, though, when you try to make a process take independent values on disjoint intervals, like a white noise, you won't get convergence, unless you shrink the variances so much that the limit is deterministic.

Are you trying to construct a Gaussian process $X_t$ such that $E[X_t X_s]=0$ iff $s\neq t$? You can simply use the Kolmogorov existence theorem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511263/does-a-gaussian-process-with-diagonal-covariance-matrix-exist
